# Empty response is showing in Jmeter after uploading PDF but in Postman success response showing

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Uploaded a doc by adding the following details in the file upload

File path:added the PDF in bin folder
Parameter name : Documentfile
MIME Type: application/json

I am getting empty response but in Postman it is working and getting the success response

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possible ways to upload a file in JMeter and in Postman. Unfortunately we cannot help you with JMeter configuration without seeing how is Postman set up.

The only piece of advice we can provide is that given you're capable of successfully executing the request in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. [Set Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. Copy the file you're uploading to JMeter's "bin" folder
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will intercept the request and generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)